# ckeditor character count on multiple textareas with wordcount plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have multiple ckeditor textareas on single page, and I need to limit character count for all of them combined.
Is it possible to do it with ckeditor, or is it possible to get that value to javascript variable so I can add them and create alert that way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know the ID of each CKEditor instances then you can use the getData method or you can use `CKEDITOR.instances` to get all instances on a page and have logic in place as needed.

```
for (var id in CKEDITOR.instances) {
     console.log(CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData().replace(/<[^>]*>|\s/g, '').length);
}
```

Comment: The question is about wordcount plugin